# When using 'gcloud run deploy', how can I specify the service name with command line args?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

When using `gcloud run deploy`, how can I specify the service name with command-line args? I'm hoping to prevent the need for interactivity at deploy-time.

I'm currently deploying my service like so:

```sh
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<TAG> --platform managed
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a service parameter, which is positional as opposed to named.

From the docs:

```
gcloud run deploy [[SERVICE] --namespace=NAMESPACE] etc...
```

So you could do this:

```
gcloud run deploy <SERVICE_NAME> --image gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<TAG> --platform managed
```

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#POSITIONAL-ARGUMENTS